# comparision b/w elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

in this code i want to take no. of testcases by keyboard input and rest is the same problem. only what i am doing is like. if i take 2 test cases then it shud be print the result based on both cases after taking the complete input. For example: INPUT testcases : 2 //case1// 5(no of building) 7 5 2 11 1 //case2// 3(no. of building) 1 2 3 OUTPUT 7//OUTPUT FOR 1ST CASE// 0//OUTPUT FOR 2ND CASE// HOPE, NOW PROBLEM IS CLEAR
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Komal {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter the test cases");
      int T=sc.nextInt();
      for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
      { 
       System.out.println("total no of building");
       int n=sc.nextInt();
       int ar[]=new int[n];
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
        System.out.println("enter the heights");
        ar[j]=sc.nextInt();

       }


       for(int j=1;j<ar.length;j++)
       {int sum=0;
        if(ar[0]<ar[i])
               {
                break;
               }else
                {
                sum +=  (ar[0]-ar[i]);

                }
        System.out.println(sum);
       }


      }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us some code that you tried, and describe exactly where you ran into difficulties.

Comment: Yole: hey man now please see the problem, hope now you will understand better that what i want to do?

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I still don't see any code that you tried.

Comment: @kunalvarshney We understand the description, what we don't understand is what is stopping you from writing any code.

Comment: BTW if all you want to do is find the first element which is greater than the first, I suggest you use a loop and a comparison, you don't need to do subtraction or addition

Comment: @kunalvarshney yole means show us what you've tried to solve the problem.
PS: if you want a newline don't press enter but leave two spaces in the end of the line instead(when posting questions/answers/etc)

Comment: @PeterLawrey nothing is stopping me from writing any code.., the only thing is i don't know the logic behind it. so please let me know the logic behind this please so that i can write the code :)

Comment: I explained that in my last comment.  I suggest you start writing code and show us what you have done.  Do you know how to write an index loop, an if comparison etc?

Comment: no that's why i am asking :( i don't know how to make comparision.

Comment: int arr[]=new int [n];                                                    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)                                                   { System.out.println("elements");                                  arr[j]=sc.nextInt();                                                now what to do after taking the elements to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static int SumUntilBigger(int[] a)
{
   int sum=0;
   for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
   {
      if(a[i]<=a[0])
         sum+=a[0]-a[i];
      else
         return sum;            
   }
   return sum;//will reach this statement if all the elements are bigger than the first one
}
```

this compares each element with the first element and when the element is bigger it just return the sum and exits from method, if all elements are bigger than the first one just return the sum of all differences.
you can use it in main like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the size of the array");
    int size=s.nextInt();
    int[] a=new int[size];
    System.out.println("enter the array values");
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)        
        a[i]=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The differences sum : "+SumUntilBigger(a));
}
```

Comment: what is a general case ? creating a separate method for the algo?

Comment: you mean like asking the user for input?

Comment: @kunalvarshney move System.out.println(sum) outside the loop

Comment: @kunalvarshney and any thing printed to screen too so you don't print messages many times.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code. Luckily i had my laptop running and this isn't a very difficult program.

```
public class TillGreater{

public static void main(String args[]){

    int[] ar = {5,4,2,7,1};
    int sum=0;

    for(int i = 1 ; i < ar.length;i++){

        if(ar[0]<ar[i]){
            break;
        }else{
            sum = sum + (ar[0]-ar[i]);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(sum);


}
```

}

Comment: Thnx a lot!! Got it :)